# Лишние переносы строк в Инструменты разработчика, при копировании CSS из Chrome в Notepad++

Tags: windows, google-chrome, notepad++, инструменты-разработчика

Название поста изменилось само. Я писал о проблеме **Инструменты разработчика** при копировании из него появляются переносы.

Проблема появилась недавно, не знаю с чем это связано, скорее всего обновления...

Допустим я отредактировал css код и скопировал его

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вставил в редактор notepad++ и получается вот что:

```html
.hqOACe.ul-u-button .ul-u-button__button {
    background-color: rgba(252, 251, 249, 0);
    padding: 14
px
 85
px
;
    border: 2
px
 solid rgb(98, 98, 98);
    border-radius: 10
px
;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Появляются пробелы между значением и PX, приходится удалять, это отнимает много времени. Такое происходит куда бы я это не вставил.

Может быть параметры какие отключить, не знаю что делать, подскажите.

Виндовс 10, 11
Chrom версия 95.0.4638.54 (Официальная сборка), (64 бит)

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: нажми комбинацию клавиш ctrl + z после вставки текста. я так решил!